# How to fix a deleted git commit branch or refs?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

Ok, I got a little problem with git. Seems by accidentally, I delete one of git commit branch / refs / or something. So.... every time I try to use the "git push" there is always an error like below :

```
Counting objects: 62, done.
error: unable to find 917c9bbd15d005484257180c1de94a479d7a7a43
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
fatal: unable to read 917c9bbd15d005484257180c1de94a479d7a7a43
fatal: early EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'slk@busaway.org:studentreg.git'
```

how to fix this ?  I tried the "git pull / git fsck / " and none has working so far... >.<"

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: `or something` is not going to cut it. Compare with another git repo what folder you are missing under .git folder

Comment: Looks like you deleted a git object …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
git config --add core.compression -1
```

and push again, should resolve.